# Text not being rendered in Base64 encoded SVG

Tags: image, svg, base64

I'm rendering an SVG image using

```
<img src="data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8;base64," + src />
```

where src is the Base64 encoded SVG image. Everything in the picture displays correctly except for the text in the  fields which are not displayed at all. This problem exists in Chrome, but not in Internet Explorer. Any ideas on how to get around this problem?

If I right-click on the displayed picture, download it and view it in Linux's Image Viewer, the text shows up perfectly again.

Edit: Example of SVG image:

```
<svg width="700" height="220" title="test2" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <text y="100" x="90" dy=".32em" text-anchor="end">
    12                
  </text> 
</svg>
```

Comment: Can you add the svg content to your question?

Comment: Try supplying a font-size attribute. Maybe you're suffering from this: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=68090

Answer (score 0):

In my case was a problem, that a have created `<text>` as `document.createElement('text')` and the svg result looked like this:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <text xmlns y="100" x="90" dy=".32em" text-anchor="end">
     12                
  </text> 
</svg>
```

And after encoded to base 64 using `window.btoa()` the text also not being rendered.
In my case **the reason** was in an empty `xmlns` attribute in `text` tag.

Solution: I have created element using `document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'text')`. It creates an element with the specified namespace URI and qualified name.